# ansible's template include with context

Tags: templates, jinja2, ansible

I am playing with ansible for almost two weeks now but I didn't figure out how template inclusion with contexts *really* works.

[Jinja's documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#import-visibility) says :

> By default, included templates are passed the current context [...]

From this statement, I tried the following :

- in the roles I apply on my servers, I export a fact that describe what check to be instanciated on each hosts (I'm trying to make a *smart* nagios_server role).

  ```
  - name: tell nagios what to monitor
    set_fact:
      nagios_monitor="{{ nagios_monitor }} dns"
  ```
- in the nagios role, I render a main template that will instanciate all the checks in one file. The checks themselves are defined in included templates.

In roles/nagios_server/tasks/main.yml :

```
- name: configure Nagios checks
  template: src="{{ item }}.cfg.j2" dest="/etc/nagios3/conf.d/{{ item }}.cfg"
  with_items:
    - hosts
    - commands
    - checks
    - defaults
  notify:
    - restart nagios
```

In roles/nagios_server/templates/checks.cfg.j2 :

```
{% for host in groups['all'] %}
  {% set checks = hostvars[host]['nagios_monitor'].strip().split(" ") %}
  # Checks for {{ host }}
  {% for elmt in checks %}
    {% if elmt != "" %}
      {% include "checks/"+elmt+".cfg.j2" with context %}
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

in roles/nagios_server/templates/checks/dns.cfg.j2 :

```
define service {
    host_name             {{ host }}
    service_description   DNS lookup
    check_command         check_dns_lookup
    use                   generic-service
}
```

And when I run the playbook, I get the following error :

```
fatal: [vagrant] => {'msg': "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: One or more undefined variables: 'host' is undefined", 'failed': True}
```

Am I missing something ? How am I supposed to make it work ?

Comment: You can find the complete code at https://github.com/billietl/servconfig if you want more informations.

Comment: I moved the github repo to https://github.com/billietl/ansible-playground, so I can use github.com/billietl/servconfig for myself

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Jinja 2.0, it is to be expected. As mentioned in the [documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#import-visibility) :

> ### Note:
>
> In Jinja 2.0, the context that was passed to the included
>   template did not include variables defined in the template.
>    As a matter of fact, this did not work:
>
> ```
> {% for box in boxes %}
>    {% include "render_box.html" %}
> {% endfor %}
> ```
>
> The included template `render_box.html` is *not* able to access *box* in Jinja > 2.0. As of Jinja 2.1, `render_box.html` *is* able to do so.